# How to Display date as day/month/year

Tags: php

I want to display my date as day/month/year.

example 31st October 2011

```
echo '<h4>Date Of Birth: '.$row['dob'].'</br></h4>';
```

Comment: What format does $row['dob'] hold?

Comment: Give us an example response/output that shows from $row['dob'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code ::-

```
echo '<h4>Date Of Birth: '.date('dS F Y', strtotime($row['dob'])).'</br></h4>';
//                               ^^^^^^^ Here the is format of date, in which format you want.
```

**Output will be ::-**

> 31st October 2011

For more you can refer [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Yeah that worked perfect very simple solution I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $mydate = "2010-03-3";
    $newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($mydate));
    $new_date = date('dS F Y', strtotime($newDate));
    echo $new_date;
    ?>

    /*Out Put*/
   03rd March 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you have that data stored as or you can convert it to 3 variables representing DD MM YYYY then I'd suggest creating array of months and an array of *post-fixes*(don't know how to call it, but in your example it's 31**st**) and getting DD % 10 to use reminder for *post-fix* array

```
$month = ['January','February',....,'December'];   //remember it's $month[MM-1];

$post = ['th','st','nd',...,'th'] //not sure if this on is correct but hope you get the idea
```

Comment: Not sure if there are shortcut function but if there aren't the use my example, if there are then definitely use the shortcut version

Comment: Not a great way to do this, especially considering PHP has inbuilt functions which resolve what the original poster requires to fix what he needs done.

Comment: @Lachie If you just could read my comment i wrote 10 minutes before you...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('dS F Y', strtotime($row['dob']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php). I normally avoid `strtotime()` conversions.

Heres a working solution:

```
<?php
   $date = '2016-11-12';
   $newDate = new DateTime($date);
   echo $newDate->format('jS F Y');
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 12th November 2016